# How to use dvbsnoop for analyzing stream

Tags: http-live-streaming, dvb

Has anybody used dvbsnoop (http://dvbsnoop.sourceforge.net) MPEG stream analyzer for analyzing transport streams?
I have transport segments (.ts) of 10 seconds generated to transport using Http live server.
I wan to analyze them to get the details technical report for every ts segment.
What i read on the dvbsnoop site, they have given options to filter ts traffic on the network but can we use it to analyze ts bunch of segments files.

Is there any other tools that can do this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

DVBSnoop can very well be used for this purpose. The tool basically analyzes all available PID and the program map of the stream. Also, decodes and displays the *descriptors* in the stream. It *deosn't* decode the video. What do you really want?

And of course, there are other tools like TSReader. But DVBsnoop is the only tool of its type in open source.

Comment: i am totally new in using dvbsnoop. Would you please tell me which code should i use to analyze MPEG Transport Stream ?

Answer (score 0):

A nice tool for analyzing TS files content is [StreamGuru MPEG Analyzer](http://www.streamguru.de/mpeg-analyzer/). It can also decode the audio and video paquets. It's not free but you can download a 30 days trial.